# "headline" vs "heading" vs "header"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

In the question [are "header" and "heading" interchangable in the context of "information at the top of something"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191301/are-header-and-heading-interchangable-in-the-context-of-information-at-the) an answer explains how  `header` is a part of the page (opposite of footer) while `heading` is a part of the text (as leading into a new section, chapter, column and alike).

Okay, understood. Then I just need to understand the difference between the words:

> heading
>
> headline

Can I use these words fully interchangeably?

Answer (score 3):

"Headline" is normally used when an article appears as one of a collection of articles, such as a newspaper. If the article is reprinted separately, the headline becomes the "title". While a headline can also be called a heading, the term "heading" is more often used for what goes at the top of a section or sub-section of an article. It can also refer to what goes above a chart or figure, although that is more often called the chart title or figure title.

In fact, I would avoid the word "headline" except in reference to a newspaper or some publication or other text organized in a way very similar to a newspaper.

Answer (score 2):

A headline is at the beginning of an article, and oftentimes is a (one-line) summary of the *whole* article.
On the other hand, a heading is for a *section* of the article.